# What command line build tools (like make) can I use with Mono C#?

Tags: c#, mono

I need to use C# on Mac, and I have Mono.
What command line tools are for building purposes Mono/C#?

- Can I just use make?
- Or is there any tool for that just like Ant for Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Mono project has its own version of MSBuild, [xBuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build).

Answer (score 2):

There is NAnt. Development of NAnt starts to get faster again, so we'll see a new release soon ;)

-sa

Answer (score 1):

On *nix platforms, you can simply use `make` to build and deploy your .NET libraries/applications.

It works quite well and is what Mono itself does when you build from source. Mono will first build `mcs` and then use the newly built `mcs` to build the framework assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

My vote for rake:

- [Home](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Rake)
- [Tutorial](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=1006101)
- [Rake and c#](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=1006101)

You can create a task like this:

```
SRC = FileList[ '*.cs']

FULL_NAME = "foo.exe"
TARGET = 'library|winexe|exe'
REFS = ["a.dll","b.dll"]
...
task :compile do
   sh "#{CSC} -debug -out:#{FULL_NAME} -target:#{TARGET}  -lib:#{BUILD_DIR}-r:#{REFS.join(',')} #{SRC}"
end
```